# Hover spanning the page

Tags: html, css

Having an issue with my CSS where I can click on the anchor element without being directly overtop of it but rather in line with it.

[Screenshot of whats going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h28xE.png)

I have my anchor tag in a div like so

```
<div class="footer">
    <a id="foo" href="foo" target="_blank">
        <p id="foo">foo</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.footer {
    color: rgb(170,170,170);
    position: relative;
    bottom:0px;
 }

#foo {
    color: rgb(170,170,170);
    text-align: center;
}

#foo:hover {
    color:rgb(220,220,220);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you not want to be able to click it unless you hover the text itself?

Comment: Yes I only want to be able to click unless I'm over the text

Comment: I suspect your element is spanning the whole width of the page. Try setting a width with responsive measurements.

Answer (score 1):

You have your tags reversed. Put your `<a>` inside your `<p>`, like this:

```
<div class="footer">
  <p id="foo"><a href="foo" target="_blank">foo</a></p>
</div>
```

Also, eliminate the id reference in your `<a>` tag. It will inherit the id from the `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the paragraph tag usage within the anchor link. It is not a good practice to use block level elements inside the inline elements. I have updated the paragraph to span which will work fine now for you.

```
<div class="footer"><!-- block element-->
    <a id="foo" href="foo" target="_blank"><!--inline element-->
        <span id="foo">foo</span><!--inline element-->
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two ID's in your HTML file. 
Just remove `<p>` like this:

```
<div class="footer">
    <a id="foo" href="foo" target="_blank">foo</a>
</div>
```

also if you want to center foo in this case you can do by giving width to element and setting margin to auto.

```
#foo {  
    color:rgb(170,170,170);  
    width: 100%;  
    margin: auto;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` tags are block level tags. They will fill, horizontally, their parent container. If you need to use a `<p>` for some reason, in your css change it to:

```
footer {
  text-align: center;
}
.foo {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

However, your best bet is to swap the `<p>` for a `<span>`. Spans are not block level, so you can maneuver them more without the necessary overrides to browser default behavior.